# Passing parameters from C# to C++ CLI DLL

Tags: c#, c++, clr

I'm not good at all with C++, so please excuse me if this is easy. I have had to write 2 C++ DLL's in order to call functions in an SDK that we have to use. The first is a native C++ DLL, which imports the SDK functionality. The second is a CLI C++ DLL, which calls the first DLL. The second DLL is referenced in a C# project and is then called in order to communicate with the SDK from within C#, as I have no other way of talking to the C++ SDK from C# (P/Invoke, etc, nothing works). My main problem is how to pass values from C# to the C++ DLL. When I debug, my values come through empty Here are small snippets which summarize what I've done.

C++ Native DLL.h

```
namespace N
{
  class __declspec(dllexport) C
  {
  public:
    int Write(char a[14], char* B);
  }
}
```

C++ Native DLL.cpp

```
namespace N
{
  int N::C::Write(char a[14], char* B)
  {
    // Here I need to add a 1 in front and \0 at the end of variable a
    char t[16] = {0};
    t[0] = 0x31;
    strcpy(&t[1], a);
  }
}
```

C++ CLI DLL.h

```
namespace N
{
  class C;
  namespace NN
  {
    public ref class CC
    {
    public:
      int Write(char a[14], char* B);
    }
  }
}
```

C++ CLI DLL.cpp

```
N::NN::C::CC() : _impl(new N::NN::C())
{
}

int Write(char a[14], char* B)
{
  return _impl->Write(a, B);
}
```

My big problem is how to pass the values from C# to the CLI dll so they are usable. I cannot change the data types or definitions in the C++ dll's. At the moment this is what I have in C#, after referencing the CLI dll:

C# method (partial):

```
N.NN.C.CC c = new N.NN.C.CC();
byte[] ba = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("11111111111111");
byte[] bB = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("BBBBBB");
unsafe
{
  sbyte* bpa;
  sbyte* bpB;
  fixed (byte* pa = ba)
  {
    bpa = (sbyte*)pa;
  }
  fixed (byte* pB = bB)
  {
    bpB = (sbyte*)pB;
  }
  int iResult = c.Write(bpa, bpB);
}
```

This is all done in VS 2012. My problem is getting the first parameter a to be usable in the first DLL. Please let me know if I should give more details anywhere or try explain better, but I hope this will suffice.